# Custom date widget in django?

Tags: python, django

In my current application, which is based on python and django, I created a custom widget for date.

```
from datetime import date
from django.forms import widgets

class DateSelectorWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        # create choices for months, years
        # example below, the rest snipped for brevity.
        years = [(year, year) for year in range(1945, 2016)]        
        months = [(1,'Jan'),(2,'Feb')]
        _widgets = (        
            widgets.Select(attrs=attrs, choices=months),
            widgets.Select(attrs=attrs, choices=years),
        )
        super(DateSelectorWidget, self).__init__(_widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return [value.month, value.year]
        return [None, None]

    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        return u''.join(rendered_widgets)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        datelist = [
            widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)
            for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]
        try:
            D = date(day=1, month=int(datelist[0]),
                    year=int(datelist[1]))
        except ValueError:
            return ''
        else:
            return str(D)
```

It's working fine when form is being loaded (return date object), but when I submit the form and left some of fields as empty in the form then I am getting the following error.

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'

Exception Location:     /var/www/stacks/django-apps/kkk/apps/oooomonth_year.py in decompress, line 21
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error here,

```
def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return [value.month, value.year]
        return [None, None]
```

`value` object has no attribute month. if you want to know the value attributes `print dir(value)`. In this value is a string.

**Update:**

check the attribute `hasattr(value, 'month')`. I hope this helps you.

Comment: t's working fine when form is being loaded (return date object), but when I submit the form and left some of fields as empty in the form then I am getting the following error.

Comment: hey, then check the attributes for that object(i.e; value) using dir.

Answer (score 0):

Its came into existence when post data bind into form. (Not stored into DB due validation message or any other issue). since

```
def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return [value.month, value.year]
        return [None, None]
```

above method is  handling date only when date is storing into DB. but when form is not submitted successfully then its behaves like "Str object". so you need to update above method by below defined method:

```
def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            import types
            try:
                if type(value) == types.StringType:
                    from datetime import datetime as dt
                    tmp_date = dt.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
                    return [tmp_date.month, tmp_date.year]
                else:
                    return [value.month, value.year]
            except:
                raise
        else:
            return [None, None]
```

Now this method  will handle both case either form submitted or not.